# Bulma form control width inhibited when wrapped in form tag

Tags: html, css, bulma

When following the Bulma documentation, you can wrap an `input.input` with a `p.control` in order to style it and have it spread the width of the container. But, when the container is a form (which it is likely to be) the controls shrink down to their default size. What am I doing wrong?

Code sample below:

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Login
    </div>
    <div class="panel-block">
        <form>
            <p class="control has-icon">
                <input class="input is-expanded" type="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email" autofocus>
                <span class="icon is-small">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="control has-icon">
                <input class="input is-expanded" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                <span class="icon is-small">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="control">
                <button class="button is-success" type="submit">
                    Login
                </button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I found the answer, annoyingly staring me in the face: you need to set the class of the `form` to `control`.

```
<div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Login
    </div>
    <div class="panel-block">
        <form class="control">
            <p class="control has-icon">
                <input class="input is-expanded" type="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email" autofocus>
                <span class="icon is-small">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="control has-icon">
                <input class="input is-expanded" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
                <span class="icon is-small">
                    <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
                </span>
            </p>
            <p class="control">
                <button class="button is-success" type="submit">
                    Login
                </button>
            </p>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the form, you will need to enclose each input element with the panel-block class.

From [bulma panel documentation](http://bulma.io/documentation/components/panel/).

Sample Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.3.1/css/bulma.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="panel">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        Login
    </div>

    <div class="panel-block">
      <p class="control has-icon">
        <input class="input is-expanded" type="email" placeholder="E-mail Address" name="email" autofocus>
        <span class="icon is-small">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>

    <div class="panel-block">
      <p class="control has-icon">
        <input class="input is-expanded" type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password">
        <span class="icon is-small">
          <i class="fa fa-lock"></i>
        </span>
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-block">
      <p class="control">
        <button class="button is-success" type="submit">
          Login
        </button>
      </p>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's the [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/behorulako/edit?html,output).

Comment: Then how does the form determine the input controls in scope? i.e. where does the form tag go?

Comment: Your code also introduces extra panel blocks, which doesn't meet the intent.